# Export HTML table with rowspan and colspan as XLSX or XLS Without Plugins

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xlsx

I have HTML Table that I want to convert to xlsx or xls without using plug-ins. I want to also add colors as I have a headers and a sub-headers.

I thought about xml then converting it to xls but I couldn’t find much. I also tried CSV but I learned during the process that CSV is bot going to satisfy my needs.

Comment: You could do it with powershell.

Comment: if its xml you dont need to convert it. excel will open an xml file as a spreadsheet